# how to implement a SP saml 2 with mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, saml, saml-2.0

i'm working in a project to implement SP saml 2.0 and a third party would implement the Idp i'm pretty new on saml, so my i was wondering if somebody has or know about some sample to implement the SP in MVC 4, i want to try to build my own SP, that is possible?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it is possible. You need to implement a SAML stack on your side.

Refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/search/label/SAML) and the two links at the top of that post.

There are some open-source and some commercial stacks. The commercial ones have a lot of sample code and support.